# Jasper + ireport + dynamic Image Creation

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i´m trying to generate a picture.
It should contain a base Picture (JPG, PNG,...) which is loaded from a mysql BLOB field
On this picture i would like to draw some circles at x/y ...
In the first step i had used the example from Ireports UltimateGuide, which describes SVG Rendering via JRAbstractSvgRenderer interface like this:

```java
public class drawpicture extends JRAbstractSvgRenderer {

    String drawstring = "something";

    public void render(Graphics2D g2d, Rectangle2D rect) throws JRException {
        System.out.println("render");
        AffineTransform savedTrans = g2d.getTransform();
        Font savedFont = g2d.getFont();
        // Paint a nice background...
        g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.ORANGE,
                0, (int) rect.getHeight(), Color.PINK));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, (int) rect.getWidth(), (int) rect.getHeight());
        Font myfont = new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 50);
        g2d.setFont(myfont);
        FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
        String text = drawstring;
        TextLayout textLayout = new TextLayout(text, myfont, frc);
        Shape outline = textLayout.getOutline(null);
        Rectangle r = outline.getBounds();
        // Translate the graphic to center the text
        g2d.translate(
                (rect.getWidth() / 2) - (r.width / 2),
                rect.getHeight() / 2 + (r.height / 2));
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.draw(outline);
        // Restore the Graphics2D affine transform
        g2d.setFont(savedFont);
        g2d.setTransform(savedTrans);
    }
}
```

That works works fine, so that i can draw a Image via Java Interface and show it in Ireports Image field.
I can also show the BLOB field in an ireport Textfield.

But i can not load Blob field, draw something in it and show it in the Image Field.

Did have someone an idea ?

Thank you and Best regards
Christian

P.S.: I´m using Ireport 4.1.3 with netBeans 7.0.1

Comment: Hi @all.
-> Solved
I´m using 2 ImageBoxes in Ireport
1 -> Picture
1 -> "Marker mask" (generated via Java)
(here is the trick to generate a transparent mask via Alpha Channel)

BR

Comment: It's an interesting question. Could you post your answer as an answer instead of as a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the below mentionend comment as answer, as desired.

Solved

Now i´m using 2 ImageBoxes in Ireport

1 -> Picture from BLOB Field

2 -> "Marker mask" (generated via Java)

here is the trick to generate a transparent mask via Alpha Channel

Marker are excluded from transparency !! :-)